# Wsadmin script for linux

Tags: linux, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I need functional wsadmin script for OS Linux. I want to deploy my application from linux into remote WAS server. I was looking for everywhere, but I found same erroneous scripts.

My current script ending with exception:

```
  [exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/ws/scripting/WasxShell
     [exec] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.scripting.WasxShell
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [exec]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
     [exec]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
     [exec] Could not find the main class: com.ibm.ws.scripting.WasxShell.  Program will exit.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: WAS tag in _not_ for WebSphere App Server

Comment: there's a chance that your CLASSPATH is wrong, check it twice.

Comment: Why is this closed? The other question/answer has nothing at all in common with this. I have the same problem. It's about Linux here. It IS possible to deploy on a remote machine, however it's not clear, if it's possible on a non AIX and non Windows OS. If someone find's out it's a pity they cannot answer here. I assume it is, because the wsadmin script contains Linux specific conditions.

Comment: Mine is finally working now. Check the version of com.ibm.ws.admin.client_....jar in the sh-script. Also notice there were lots of other things I had to fix to get it working on Linux. Unfortunately this question has been closed.